# IOS GLKit : Turing GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X stops object picking

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit, picking

I am using pixel colour picking to work out which OpenGL object I have clicked on and it works brilliantly

As soon as I turn GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X on in the view, the picking stops working?

I have tried turning this on and off when I touch the screen but only works once.

Picking code:

```
  GLKView *glkView = (GLKView*)[self view];
  UIImage *snapshot = [glkView snapshot];
  GLKVector4 colour = [snapshot pickPixelAtX:xPos Y:yPos];

@implementation UIImage (NDBExtensions)

- (GLKVector4)pickPixelAtX:(NSUInteger)x Y:(NSUInteger)y {

    CGImageRef cgImage = [self CGImage];
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);

    if ((x < width) && (y < height))
    {
        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage);
        CFDataRef bitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);
        const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(bitmapData);
        size_t offset = ((width * y) + x) * 4;

        UInt8 b = data[offset+0];
        UInt8 g = data[offset+1];
        UInt8 r = data[offset+2];
        UInt8 a = data[offset+3];

        CFRelease(bitmapData);

        return GLKVector4Make(r, g, b, a );

    }
    return GLKVector4Make(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this using the code from this

[OpenGL ES 2.0 Object Picking on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774197/opengl-es-2-0-object-picking-on-ios)

Very good answer, basically GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X does not work with picking and so you need to make another render buffer