# Learning OpenGL on Xcode

Tags: xcode, opengl, graphics

How do you code in OpenGL on Xcode without going into the app-templates ?

Comment: App templates?  Do you mean by choosing Cocoa Application etc.?  You have to create a new project using templates, unless you want to make it using C.  If you wanna use C, then just choose command-line tool.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [OpenGL ES 2.0 Object Picking on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774197/opengl-es-2-0-object-picking-on-ios/)

It has some info and gl setup examples. Still it would be good to get gl template from apple examples.

Comment: thank you all for your help - I'm just beginning openGL, I'm taking a class this semester. I don't know much of the language yet.  What I want to know is "how" I code, ie, where do I write openGL code. Suppose all I wanted to do was draw a single point, where would I write the code for that, and what library(ies) would I need to import  ?

Comment: This requires a bit of storyboard work and also coding. Let me know your email, I will send you some working proto with bunch of very common gl things (drawing objects, picking, etc)

Comment: btw, do you need it for osx or ios?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Mac OS X supports OpenGL only up to 3.2, so you'd be limited to GLSL version 1.3.

Comment: It actually supports GLSL 1.5