# 3D object render using .obj file in iOS and add dynamic texture at touched position

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opengl-es

I have good hands on objective-C but not on OpenGl, Please help me with the problem below,

I have a human skeleton body as .obj file. I am able to render it on View.

But I am facing following problems

1. Rotation about x,y axis.
2. Moving 3D model relatively to any point.
3. I am not able to detect body part touch event. e.g When I long press on left hand then app should detect as user click on left hand.
4. Add marker (Any texture) at runtime on body part where user touched.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at glRotate, glTranslate and the picking. I prefer implementing my own picking than using build-in OpenGL picking. Good luck.

Comment: @gouessej: There is no build-in picking in OpenGL

Comment: It's also very unlikely that glRotate, glTranslate, etc. are going to be available on iOS. GLKit (specifically [this part](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrixStack/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011001)) was created to replace that stuff in ES 2.0.

Comment: @BDL GL_SELECT is deprecated but it doesn't mean that there is no build-in picking in OpenGL: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glSelectBuffer.xml Anyway, it isn't available in OpenGL ES.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Sandeep should have mentioned that he looks for a solution for OpenGL ES instead of adding the tags "opengl" and "opengl-es". It's confusing even though iOS supports only the latter and not the former. OpenGL ES 1.1 supports glTranslate: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glTranslate.xml

Comment: @gouessej: Yeah, I'm used to seeing iOS in the title and incorrect tags in the question. That's usually fixed pretty quickly, in fact I'll do it right now.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Sandeep should use GLKMatrixStackRotate and GLKMatrixStackTranslate instead, shouldn't he?

Comment: @Sandeep This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774197/opengl-es-2-0-object-picking-on-ios

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and Suggestions, if you have any working example please share code or link.